# Regular Expression - shortest match

Tags: regex

I need to parse through regular expression a HTML string, were the KEY is located after the VALUE I need to extract.

Sample original string:

```
<TR><TD>VAL1</TD><TD>KEY1</TD></TR><TR><TD>VAL2</TD><TD>KEY2</TD></TR>
```

When I try to extract VAL2 with:

```
<TD>(.*?)</TD><TD>KEY2</TD>
```

I actually get

```
VAL1KEY1VAL2
```

How can I resolve this problem, assuming the Keys are constant and the values are changing?

Thanks in advance,
Michael

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
<TD>([^<]*)</TD><TD>KEY2</TD>
```

instead. Your lazy quantifier *would* ensure the shortest match *but from the first matching position*. In this case starting at the first `<TD>`. The solution above sidesteps the problem by restricting the characters that can appear in a value, so it won't ever span multiple tags.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what language you're using, but if it's PHP, I think you'd be better off using [DOM](http://ca.php.net/dom) rather than parsing this using a regular expression.

Here's one way to do it:

```
<?php

$html="<TR><TD>VAL1</TD><TD>KEY1</TD></TR><TR><TD>VAL2</TD><TD>KEY2</TD></TR>";

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

print_r($doc->getElementById(1)->tagName);

$output=array();
$n=0;
while ($val = $doc->getElementsByTagName('td')->item($n++)) {
  $key = $doc->getElementsByTagName('td')->item($n++);
  $output[$key->textContent]=$val->textContent;
}

print_r($output);
```

And here's what it shows when I run it.

```
Array
(
    [VAL1] => KEY1
    [VAL2] => KEY2
)
```

Comment: How do you know it's PHP they're after?

Comment: +1 for not posting YAPPeR ("Yet Another Pseudo-Parsing Regex").

Comment: @Joey - good point.  I think I've been reading too many of the same question.  Answer edited accordingly.

Comment: CodeGnome, for something as trivial as that it's perfectly fine to use a regex by the way. No nesting structures, definitely a regular language you expect. Heck, why not regex? They exist for that purpose :)